# Reduce loadtime in games merging two folders across ramdisk and local disk

Tags: windows, software-raid, ramdisk

I've found a program to emulate a drive in my memory, RAMDrive.
RAMDrive creates a drive (G:) on my computer, which allows me to have super fast read/write on that drive.
Now I was thinking I could move the heavy files for games into this folder (skins, map, etc.), to make the load of a game super fast, but since I have limited space on my RAMDrive (G:) I can only put a few of the files there - so my question is

**Can I merge files from two different folders, to appear as one?**

eg. 
g:\LOL\ containing the "data2.cab" file only, for LOL and
c:\games\LOL containing the rest of the game

Or do I simply have to rely on Windows' spanned volume and hope the file would end up the right location

Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `mklink` command to create a symbolic link:

```
C:\mklink /D c:\games\LOL g:\LOL
```

More details [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/).

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't a big of a benefit as everyone thinks.

Whenever LOL tries to load `data2.cab`, Windows will automatically cache it in RAM for you, without you having to do anything. And when you stop playing LOL and pick another game, Windows will automatically purge `data2.cab` from memory to make space for the next game's files.

You *can* use a RAM disk to forcefully reserve memory for a game's data files, yes, but performance of everything else on the system will suffer because Windows will have less RAM available for it to use as a disk cache. Windows will automatically optimize available memory for whatever application you happen to be using, whether it be LOL, web browsing, Skype, or whatever if you just leave it alone and let it do it's thing.

Comment: Well, it's true but it's still fun to play around with.